# How can I combine Columns in a Pandas Object?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big Pandas Object with three date columns, which I would like to merge and save in another pandas object. The data looks like that:

```
name  | review | sys_date | rev_date   | m_date
user1 | hello  | 1.1.2018 | 31.12.2017 | 1.1.2018
user2 | hi     | 1.1.2018 | 28.12.2017 | 31.1.2017
user3 | huhu   | 1.1.2018 | 27.12.2017 | 28.1.2017
```

I seperated the date with following code:

```
dim_sysdate = final[[sysdate]]
dim_rev_date = final[[rev_date ]]
dim_m_date = final[[m_date]]
```

Then I tried to combine the date into one column. First try:

```
frames = [dim_sysdate, dim_rev_date, dim_m_date]
final_pandas= pd.concat(frames)
```

Second try:

```
final_pandas = 
dim_sysdate.dim_sysdate.combine_first([dim_rev_date.dim_rev_date, 
dim_m_date.dim_m_date]).to_frame()
--> Doesnt work: I get following msg: TypeError: Input must be Index or array-like
```

Can someone give me an advice how I can solve this problem?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: No I just want to have all three dates in one Column. The new pandas Object should just have this one column

Comment: I realized, i forgot to show the output. sorry for that. the output should look like this     new Pandas Object --> date: 1.1.2018;1.1.2018;1.1.2018;31.12.2017;28.12.2017;27.12.2017;1.1.2018;31.1.2017;28.1.2017

Comment: You might want to start thinking more specifically than "Pandas Object"s.  There's a big difference between a dataframe with one column and a series.

Comment: Can you post your desired output as formatted text in question? Looking at the accepted answer it seems you meant the semicolons to mean newline, but it's not clear on its own.

Comment: I tried to edit my orginal post but someone edited it already and my changes wont be accepted :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final_pandas = pd.concat([final['sys_date'], final['rev_date'], final['m_date']])
```

Should give you what you're looking for.

Output:

```
print(final_pandas)
#0      1.1.2018
#1      1.1.2018
#2      1.1.2018
#0    31.12.2017
#1    28.12.2017
#2    27.12.2017
#0      1.1.2018
#1     31.1.2017
#2     28.1.2017
#dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Create an empty array. Optional

df['dates'] = np.nan

def make_dates(row):
     row['dates'] = [row['sys_date'],row['rev_date'],row['m_date']]
     return row

df = df.apply(make_dates,axis=1)
```

This creates a list in the element, you could rewrite the function to combine them however you'd like.